# Why has the Si diode been open circuited?

Tags: diodes

Why has the Si diode been open circuited?

[image]

Comment: what is your reasoning?> What do you know about the properties.?

Comment: What is the relationship of the voltage drops over two parallel components (here, the diodes)? What is the actual voltage drop? What does this imply for the current through the Si diode?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I know that voltage drop across a Si diode in forward biased condition is 0.7 V.  So why has the Si diode(which is supposed to have a voltage drop of 0.7 V), have been open circuited and and why the Ge diode short circuited? If they had been connected in series the combined voltage drop offered would have been 0.7 + 0.3 = 1V. But what has to be done in case they are connected parallel as in the above case?and why?

Comment: @CL. Sir, thats exactly what I want to know. What to do in case there are different voltage drops across two devices when connected in parallel?and why?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Sorry sir, Ge diode is not short, it offers a voltge drop.

Comment: You should alread know that parallel components *always* have the same voltage drop. Now look at the voltage-vs-current curves of the diodes, and determine what the currents must be to get the same voltage drop for both.

Comment: A pond has a two part weir that sets it's depth. One part is 0.6 metres tall and next to it the other part is 0.3 metres tall. How deep is the pond?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a graph showing a germanium and silicon diode current versus voltage graph;
[image: Ge Si diode graphs]

Let's consider if you only had the germanium diode in series with the 2.2k Ohm resistor for now.  One way to solve for the voltage is to do it graphically.  This is done by plotting the load line of the resistor.  This load line is ploted by shorting the diode to and finding the current through the resistor is 5.5mA.  To find another point on the graph the diode is open circuited and the voltage is found to be 12V.  The line through (0V,5.5ma) and (12V,0mA) can be plotted plotted on this graph.  The intersection of this line and the diode curve is this diodes opperating point.

Now you should see the Ge diode limits the voltage to a little more than 0.3V.  So now if you put the Si diode back in the circuit, it can't have more than this 0.3V across it.  The Si diode at 0.3V has zero current through it.

The answer to you question is that the Si diode has been open circuited because the Ge diode limits the voltage across it to 0.3 where it has zero current.

Answer (score 2):

In finding the answer for your question look at the properties of the two different diodes.
Maybe you know the difference between a germanium and silicon diode.

If not then try to find information concerning the voltage/current characteristic of both diodes.

You can find this information in Wikipedia or the datasheets of germanium and silicon diodes.

Once you have this you should be able to answer the question yourself.

Note resulting from the comments:

The voltage drop across a diode is also the threshold for conducting or not.
In other words it is not only a voltage drop as if you are looking at two resistors in parallel. If you look again at the datasheets and you compare the voltages during the conducting state then you should be able to determine why the silicon diode remains non-conducting.

Comment: I know that voltage drop across a Si diode in forward biased condition is 0.7 V. So why has the Si diode(which is supposed to have a voltage drop of 0.7 V), have been open circuited and and why the Ge diode short circuited? If they had been connected in series the combined voltage drop offered would have been 0.7 + 0.3 = 1V. But what has to be done in case they are connected parallel as in the above case?and why?

Comment: Sorry Ge diode is not short circuited, it offers a voltage drop.

Comment: See my updated answer and think.

Answer (score 2):

You already know that an Si diode has a drop of 0.7V and a Ge diode a drop of 0.3V. That is very clear in your comments.

However, these voltage drops are not like a voltage source (they are not like a battery). These voltages are the minimum voltages that have to exist between the leads of the diode before it starts to conduct current. Below that value, the diode does not conduct current and behaves like an open circuit.

Because the Ge diode starts to conduct at 0.3V, it prevents the voltage drop between the leads of the two diodes in parallel to raise above that value, and consequently, the Si diode does not have the opportunity to have its lead voltage increased above 0.3V and it stays in the open circuit state.

Comment: Of course, this answer is not really true. The constant-voltage-drop model for diodes is still a very crude model. Some current will flow in a silicon diode with a forward voltage of 0.3V; it is not an open circuit.

Comment: Agree that some current will flow, but as I have mentioned, it will be so small compared with the Ge current that it will behave like an open circuit an its forward voltage will follow the Ge voltage drop, not its own.

Answer (score 0):

All kinds of diodes (silicon, germanium, Schottky, LEDs, Zener ...) have the property to maintain a relatively constant voltage when the current through them varies. Generally speaking, they do that by changing their static resistance as follows:

When the current I increases, the diode decreases its static resistance R with the same rate of change and v.v. So, the voltage drop across the diode V = I.R does not change. This is a simple arithmetic trick where we change the multipliers in the opposite direction and at the same rate of change; as a result, the product of multiplication does not change.

[image]

Thus, by changing their resistance opposite to the current, these "dynamic resistors" maintain a constant voltage.

When we connect two diodes in parallel, each of them tries to maintain, in the manner above, its voltage threshold (VF). The diode with higher voltage threshold tries to set it by increasing its static resistance but the diode with lower voltage does the opposite by decreasing its static resistance. Finally, the former enormously increases its resistance (open circuit) and the voltage is set only by the latter.

That is why, when we connect a Ge diode (VF = 0.4 V) to an Si diode (VF = 0.7 V) in parallel, the latter is off.

You can see how this happens in the [movie](https://photos.app.goo.gl/vnyj2jMnauDpwkcP9) from my personal Google Photos where a red LED (VF = 1.8 V) is connected in parallel to a green LED (VF = 2.5 V). As a result, the green LED is extinguished.

This trick can be used to build a simple LED voltage indicator in which two transistors control three LED (see [my Codidact paper](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/279016) and [my movie](https://photos.app.goo.gl/yYiwyc3FwVcBPiCk7)).

Comment: No, diodes don't change their "static resistance". The diode has a non-linear relationship between voltage and current, it's as simple and as complex as that. There is no little person inside the diode that looks at the current and changes the resistance. In the end, your "intuitive" explanation confuses more than it enlightens.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, Rstatic = VA/IA (Ohm's law) for the operating point A. When A moves along the vertical part of the diode IV curve, Rstatic changes because the current changes and, as a result, the voltage stays relatively constant. Everyone has such a notion, especially about Zener diode. As for the "little person inside the diode", do you know about H&H "transistor man"?

Comment: Ohm's Law does not apply to diodes. It is confusing when you talk about the "resistance" of a diode without proper qualification.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, note that Ohm's law is applied to the linear IV curve of the static resistance... not to the non-linear diode IV curve. "Static resistance" is not my invention; see, for example, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistance_and_conductance) about resistance. BTW I am rewriting my answers at the request of the moderators to disclose my affiliation to links. So you can save yourself the trouble of making fictitious edits to other people's pages; it only confuses people.

Answer (score -1):

I too had the same doubt a few days back and scavenged for an answer through the net. What I found can be condensed to 2 points:

1. P-N junction diodes act like capacitors with their depletion region acting like the insulator. Therefore the charge takes time to build up on both diodes and is not an instantaneous process. We also see that the germanium and silicon diode have 0.3 and 0.7 volts as the minimum necessary voltage therefore the analogy can be draw further that germanium has a lower capacitance than silicon, thus takes lesser time to charge and short than silicon.

[image: labelled diode pic]

Here in the starting instant, the voltage at A and C is both the same (12 volts)

2. As soon as the germanium first shorts, a voltage drop of 0.3 V occurs over it, and as B and D are equipotential there's a 11.7 volt potential at both B and D. Hence the silicon diode has now 0.3 V over it and is unable to ever switch on.

I know this thread is ancient but hey some curious wanderer might finally get salvation.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with capacitance or the time it takes to charge it.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, Abhigyan's reasoning is methodologically correct. He tries to explain the sequence of events through time (the transition) when the voltage starts to rise from zero trying to reach the maximum. Thus, first the germanium diode is switched on and it fixes the voltage at a lower value... and the silicon diode is never switched on...

Comment: @Circuitfantasist No, this explanation is not consistent with reality. Suppose we leave the Ge diode out of the circuit and allow the Si diode to become forward biased. If we then add the Ge diode in parallel with the Si diode we see that the Ge diode becomes forward biased and the Si diode is no longer forward biased. It doesn't matter which one becomes forward biased **first**.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Hey there, i am sorry if i provided the incorrect reasoning. I haven't had any practical experience with the diode configuration, rather i picked up the explanation that convinced me best from forums. Could you give any ideas that you might be having on why there's a strict preference for a diode with a lower voltage drop? and why there's no current whatsoever through the Si diode in the presence of a Ge diode in parallel.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, Okay, then let both scenarios exist. Here is a video of my students in the lab that demonstrates your approach - https://photos.app.goo.gl/vnyj2jMnauDpwkcP9.

Comment: @Circuitfantasist No. I'm not going to watch some dodgy video. Answer a simple question: If I place a Ge diode in parallel with a Si diode that is **already forward biased**, does the voltage across both diodes remain at about 0.6V or does the voltage across both diodes fall to the forward voltage of the Ge diode? owg60 explained it quite well.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Could you elaborate your ideas on the topic please. My bad i mistakenly tagged Circuitfanatisist. My last comment was directed to you

Comment: @Elliot Alderson, of course the forward voltage falls to the lower voltage. Exactly this is shown in the video where a red LED (VF = 1.8 V) is connected in parallel to a green LED (VF = 2.5 V). As a result, the green LED is extinguished.

Comment: See the answer by owg60 which explains the issue.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson i read the para by owg60 but i dont understand the implications of the said load line. Is there a simpler explanation which you can formulate which explains the phenomena? I'd like to ask this to owg60 himself but SE doesnt allow me to comment to his answer unless i have 50 rep points, nor can i really dm him in SE.